# Why gmtime() function returns NULL?

Tags: c, date, microcontroller, epoch

I am trying to set RTC time on `STM32L051T6` microcontroller using `epoch` time. So following is my code.

```
void Rtc_SetTime(uint32_t time_)
{
    struct tm* brokenTime;
    const time_t temp = 3600;

    brokenTime = gmtime(&temp);

    if (NULL == brokenTime)
    {
       printf("Error: Failed to convert time.\r\n");
    }
}
```

When I call above function. It always goes to `if` statement and prints Error. I have tried passing  values 3600, 1459841178 as arguments. All fails. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Could you call `perror` in else statement to know what happened?

Comment: Are you sure that `TIME_T` is a valid `time_t` var?

Comment: Remove the cast. If you get a compiler warning/error it means the code was wrong the whole time. You need to fix the code, not suppress the warning.

Comment: @purplepsycho perror prints "No error (errno = 0)"

Comment: Try using gmtime_r() and analyze the output itself. Not just the error code

Comment: @LPs I edited the code. TIME_T is uint32_t.

Comment: @M.M Compiler does not give any warning on the code compilation.

Comment: @Michael I am using Keil toolchain and it does not have gmtime_r() function.

Comment: Probably on your platform `time_t` is not a `uint32_t` var. I guess `long int` `int64_t`. Change the prototype to `void Rtc_SetTime(time_t time_)` and see what happen. BTW if you need a `time_t` var why did you defined that function with `uint32_t`?

Comment: @DarshanPrajapati I said to remove the cast and then look at the warnings.

Comment: @M.M I removed the cast, it does not give any warning.

Comment: @DarshanPrajapati update your question to include the code after removing the cast (and make sure you are compiling the exact code in the question)

Comment: Not possible. Your compiler will give you: `expected ‘const time_t *’ but argument is of type ‘uint32_t *’`

Comment: @M.M Updated the code exactly what I am trying to compile and run.

Comment: OK. Read the documentation for the controller you are programming. Maybe its SDK has a different time function and the C ones don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used localtime() function instead of gmtime() and it works well solving my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following here: 
http://support.raisonance.com/content/gmtime-and-localtime-broken-arm-gcc-lib

So it might not be implemented....

> I think gmtime and localtime is broken in arm-gcc lib for STM32F10x.
>
> I have try it in keil uVision and working fine there(localtime anyway,
>   gmtime not implemented in keil). gmtime and localtime is searching for
>   _sbrk when linking.
>
> "sbrkr.c: (.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'"

Comment: I have updated the code above just like you in question. It still does not work.

Comment: ok, then check the docs for your platform, gmtime might not be implemented.